# Conditional statements in SQL Server with read only access

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to assemble information from a table in SQL Server in which I only have read access.

I guess the best way to explain what I want to do is to display what I tried to do.

```
USE eMOS2
IF ( OPERATION.CLOSE_DATE WHERE WORKORDER_BASE_ID='73691' IS NULL )
    THEN 
        SELECT
            SHED_START_DATE,
            SHED_FINISH_DATE
        FROM OPERATIONS    
        WHERE WORKORDER_BASE_ID='73691'
    ELSE 
        SELECT
            SHED_START_DATE,
            CLOSE_DATE
        FROM OPERATIONS    
        WHERE WORKORDER_BASE_ID='73691'
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. I have no doubt my syntax is wrong I've tried a couple different formats, however the problem seems to be that my access is read only. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Do you get an error? WHat do you mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: @Mike that is full of syntax errors, you shouldn't need to run that to see that it isn't even close to working.

Comment: @SeanLange - agreed and noted, Just wanted the OP to expand a little bit on their post/"show their working out" :-) Hopefully my answer below will sort it for them

Comment: Sean you obviously didn't read my message. I had never formatted a conditional statement in SQL. If my syntax was correct, why would I need to ask a question? Thanks for wasting my time.

Answer (score 4):

```
select shed_startdate, isnull(close_date,shed_finish_date) 
from operations 
where workorder_base_id = '73691'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ISNULL or COALESCE.  COALESCE is probably better because it is standard sql.

```
SELECT
  SHED_START_DATE,
  COALESCE(CLOSE_DATE,SHED_FINISH_DATE) AS CLOSE_DATE
FROM OPERATIONS    
WHERE WORKORDER_BASE_ID='73691'
```